# How to load data of nested relationships inside resource class

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, collections

I am making an api to fetch all users of a group. And can't get the below format of response using  laravel resouces.
This is Group Model.

```
class Group extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'groups';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'short_name', 'description', 'settings', 'is_default'];

    protected $casts = [
        'settings' => 'array',
    ];

    public function groupUser(): HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(GroupUser::class, 'group_id', 'id')
            ->where('role', '=', 1);
    }

    public function security(): HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Security::class, 'id', 'security_atr_id');
    }
}
```

This is GroupUser Model.

```
class GroupUser extends TenantModel {

public static int$role_User = 1;
public static int $role_Organiser = 2;

protected $fillable = ['group_id', 'user_id', 'role'];

public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
}
```

}

This is User model.

```
class User extends \App\Models\User{
  protected $fillable = [];
}
```

Controller code

```
public function getGroupUsers(Request $request){
    try{
        $users = Group::with('groupUser.users')->where('id',$request->group_id)->get();
        return GroupUserResource::collection($users);
    } catch (Exception $exception){
        $this->handleIse($exception);
    }
}
```

This is the resource.

```
    class GroupUserResource extends JsonResource
   {
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'          => $this->resource->id,
            'group_name'  => $this->resource->name,
            'group_short' => $this->resource->short_name,
            'description' => $this->resource->description,
            'setting'     => $this->resource->settings,
            'is_default'  => $this->resource->is_default,
            'group_users' => $this->groupUser,
        ];
    }
}
```

This is the response curretly I am getting.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "group_name": "Backend Group 1234",
        "group_short": "Larave Group4",
        "description": "We are the people who build larave api's",
        "setting": [],
        "is_default": 0,
        "group_users": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "group_id": 2,
                "user_id": 173,
                "role": 1,
                "created_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                "users": {
                    "id": 173,
                    "fname": "ann",
                    "lname": "singh",
                    "email": "anurag@mailinator",
                    "avatar": null,
                    "identifier": null,
                    "login_count": 0,
                    "setting": null,
                    "internal_id": null,
                    "email_verified_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "group_id": 2,
                "user_id": 174,
                "role": 1,
                "created_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                "users": {
                    "id": 174,
                    "fname": "ravi",
                    "lname": "singh",
                    "email": "ravi@mailinator",
                    "avatar": null,
                    "identifier": null,
                    "login_count": 0,
                    "setting": null,
                    "internal_id": null,
                    "email_verified_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "group_id": 2,
                "user_id": 175,
                "role": 1,
                "created_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                "users": {
                    "id": 175,
                    "fname": "abc",
                    "lname": "xzyy",
                    "email": "abc@mailinator",
                    "avatar": null,
                    "identifier": null,
                    "login_count": 0,
                    "setting": null,
                    "internal_id": null,
                    "email_verified_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "group_id": 2,
                "user_id": 176,
                "role": 1,
                "created_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                "users": {
                    "id": 176,
                    "fname": "chhotu",
                    "lname": "singh",
                    "email": "chhotu@mailinator",
                    "avatar": null,
                    "identifier": null,
                    "login_count": 0,
                    "setting": null,
                    "internal_id": null,
                    "email_verified_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-08-17T08:31:53.000000Z"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I want that my response should be like

```
    {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "group_name": "Backend Group 1234",
            "group_short": "Larave Group4",
            "description": "We are the people who build larave api's",
            "setting": [],
            "is_default": 0,
            "group_users": [
                {
                        "id": 173,
                        "fname": "ann",
                        "lname": "singh",
                        "email": "anurag@mailinator",
                        "avatar": null,
                        "role" : 1,
                },
                {
                    "id": 174,
                        "fname": "anndf",
                        "lname": "singh",
                        "email": "anurag@mailinator",
                        "avatar": null,
                        "role" : 1,
                },
                
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me in this. I am stuck in getting the above data  format.
Thanks

Comment: You can use this doc, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#relationships;

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but this something which cannot be found directly in the docs.
I found the sollution.

Comment: Your naming of variables and resources doesn't match what they actually are and it makes your code very hard to read. For instance, your groups are saved to the variable $users, and your group resource is called GroupUserResource

Answer (score 0):

This line `'group_users' => $this->groupUser` is getting an entire group user model which also has the user relation loaded which is why you're getting the entire groupUser model with the nested user.

You could explicitly define which fields you want from group user with something like `$this->groupUser->name` in a nested array.

It's good practice to explicitly define what your resource is returning so you don't accidentally return the user's password in case you had overlooked returning it. You could achieve that either with a `->map` (<- the simplest way) or create a nested GroupUser resource that would define how you format your nested array.